# Using the "IN" clause with a comma delimited string from the output of a replace() function in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have an comma delimited string which I want to use in an "IN" clause of the statement.
eg: 100,101,102

Since In and "IN" clause I have to quote the individial strings, I use a replace function:
eg: select ''''||replace('100,101,102',',',''', ''')||'''' from dual;

The above query works, however, when I try to use the output of the above as an input to the "IN" clause, it returns no data. I am restricted by only SQL statements, so I cannot use PL/SQL code. Kindly help.

```
select * from employee where employee_number in (
    select ''''||replace('100,101,102',',',''', ''')||'''' from dual);
```

The above does not work. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: is the number of IDs in the list limited?

Answer (score 11):

The general approach in this case would be to parse the comma-separated list into an Oracle collection and to use that collection in your SQL statement.  Tom Kyte has an example of this in his discussion on [variable IN lists](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425).

Assuming you create the myTableType type and the in_list function from that thread, you should be able to do

```
SELECT *
  FROM employee
 WHERE employee_number IN (
    SELECT *
      FROM TABLE( in_list( p_your_comma_separated_list ) )
    )
```

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't have access to the database to change or create anything. I have only read access, hence I am restricted to only "select".

Answer (score 5):

pure SQL, but not very well tested...

```
select to_number(substr(postfix, 2, instr(postfix, ',' ,2)-2)) id 
  from (
       select substr(val, instr(val, ',', 1, n)) postfix 
         from (select ',101,102,103,' val from dual)
     , (
       select level n
         from dual 
      connect by level < 10) 
  where instr(val, ',', 1, n) > 0)
 where  instr(postfix, ',' ,2)> 2;
```

**EDIT**: improved

```
select substr(postfix, 1, instr(postfix, ',' ,1)-1)
  from (
       select substr(val, instr(val, ',',1, level)+1) postfix
         from (select ',101,102,103,' val from dual)
      connect by instr(val, ',', 2, level) > 0
  );
```

Note:

- pre/post fix your strings with comma
- <strike>adopt the upper limit (10 in the example) as per your needs</strike> (not needed in the improved version).
- use the in_list table function mentioned by Justing Cave, that's probably better :)

credit: something like that is in Stephane Faroult's book "Refactorying SQL Applications" (O'Reilly)

Comment: Hello Markus, thanks you. The solution provided by you using pure sql is working perfectly. Thanks to you and Justin for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As the comma-separated values contain only digits, why not try something as simple as using:

```
INSTR(','||my_csv_list_of_values||',', ','||my_search_value||',') <> 0
```

See this example:

```
-- some test data
with employee as (
  select 101 as employee_number from dual
  union select 200 from dual
  union select 10 from dual
  union select 102 from dual)

-- the actual query
select * from employee
  where INSTR(','||'101,102,103,104'||',', ','||employee_number||',') <> 0;
--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                   your CSV data
```

Producing:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
101
102
```

Comment: suppose if csv data passed as input varchar2 parameter to stored procedure, what changes is required in query

Answer (score 1):

You can use XMLTABLE to convert comma separated string to a table.

Example:

```
select * from employee where employee_number in (
        SELECT  TO_NUMBER (column_value)
        FROM    XMLTABLE('100,101,102') );
```

Comment: This worked for me. Wrap it in `TO_CHAR()` to get the values back to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your approach with REPLACE and IN if you format the entire select as a string - then use the string with either OPEN refcursor FOR or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **regexp_substr function** to get expected output. 
 For Example
NAMES:='SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES'; -- here "NAMES" is the variable/result of expected input.that can be use in IN Clause.

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(NAMES,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual 2  connect by regexp_substr(NAMES, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;


REGEXP_SUBSTR('SMITH,A
----------------------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
```

The above query iterates through the comma separated string, searches for the comma (,) and then splits the string by treating the comma as delimiter. It returns the string as a row, whenever it hits a delimiter.

Here is an Reference [Click Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement)

```
 SQL> select * from emp where ename in (
  2  select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  3  connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );



     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
```