# bind array in cursor using plsql

Tags: oracle, parameters, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

```
declare
  cursor lc is 
    select * 
      from (select a.lin, a.pr, 
                   b.name, sum(a.up) as u,
                   sum (a.d)         as d
              from li_dy_4 a,
                   p_list  b 
             where a.pr=b.id 
               and b.parent_id != 0 
               and a.partitionid <= 308 
               and a.partitionid >= 302 
               and a.pr in (91,80)
             GROUP BY a.pr, b.name, a.lin  
             order by d desc) ;
  rec lc%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 
  open lc;
  loop 
    FETCH lc into rec;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.pr);
    exit when lc%NOTFOUND;
  end loop;
  close lc;
END;
```

the above statement works fine for me. What I am not capable of finding anything hopeful is changing the value after the "in" statement which is `a.pr in (91,80)` 
I have listed the values here manually, but I want to pass it to the cursor as an array of numbers for `a.pr column`. In short I want to do `a.pr = idlist` wher `idlist` is an array. Please anyone tell me if my idea is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaration of multiple values in Oracle BIND Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632741/declaration-of-multiple-values-in-oracle-bind-variables)

Comment: Can you please tell what Database do you use, Oracle 10g or 11g ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to remind you, the `IN` clause supports `1000 items` only. And that could be the primary reason ,there's nothing called BULK BINDING for SELECT Queries. We have `FORALL INSERT/UPDATE`, which is like `BULK BINDING`. Unfortunately select has none.

But still you can achieve your requirement in a different fashion.

You can try a `global temporary table`(GTT) which a temporary table with "scope of the data inserted" is only to that session.

You can `FORALL INSERT` all your data for IN clause into that table, and join the TABLE to your Query.

Else you can have a `nested table` (if oracle 10g) or a simple pl/sql type itself (if oracle 11g), with all your IN class items as records and join it to your Query.

**Example: Using NESTED TABLE , effective for less number(<10000) of items**

```
CREATE TYPE pr AS OBJECT
           (pr  NUMBER);
/
CREATE TYPE prList AS TABLE OF pr;
/

declare
  myPrList prList := prList ();
  cursor lc is 
    select * 
      from (select a.lin, a.pr, 
                   b.name, sum(a.up) as u,
                   sum (a.d)         as d
              from li_dy_4 a,
                   p_list  b,
                   TABLE(CAST(myPrList as prList)) my_list
             where a.pr=b.id 
               and b.parent_id != 0 
               and a.partitionid <= 308 
               and a.partitionid >= 302 
               and a.pr = my_list.pr
             GROUP BY a.pr, b.name, a.lin  
             order by d desc) ;
  rec lc%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 
  /*Populate the Nested Table, with whatever collection you have */
  myPrList := prList ( pr(91),
                       pr(80));
  /*
     Sample code: for populating from your TABLE OF NUMBER type 

     FOR I IN 1..your_input_array.COUNT
     LOOP
          myPrList.EXTEND;
          myPrList(I) := pr(your_input_array(I));
     END LOOP;
  */
  open lc;
  loop 
    FETCH lc into rec;
    exit when lc%NOTFOUND; -- Your Exit WHEN condition should be checked afte FETCH iyself!
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.pr);
  end loop;
  close lc;
END;
/
```

Comment: ,I am using oracle11gR2.I have tried the solution you had provided and also my records are less than from  what you have mentioned.But,am getting. PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "MY_LIST"."PR": invalid identifier
PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'LC' is incomplete or malformed....what shall i do

Comment: you created the types? prList and pr , I mentioned before the PL/SQL Block ?

Comment: It should work, I tried the same and it works. Can you update wht u have shortly.. in ur question itself?

Comment: `myPrList prList := prList ();` .. you added?

Comment: my aim of using the above sample code is to create a procedure and pass variables and an array to the procedure.Execute that procedure from php by passing arguments.

Comment: yes, that is why i added a comment with a for loop using your_input_array. That could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact structure of your global table but you can use the collection  in cursor like this

```
declare
 cursor c1 is
  select last_name ls  from empc;
 type x is table of employees.last_name%type;
 x1 x := x();
 cnt integer :=0;
begin
 for z in c1 loop
  cnt := cnt +1;
  x1.extend;
  x1(cnt) := z.ls;
  if x1(cnt) is NULL then-----------
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ASHISH');
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line(cnt || ' '|| x1(cnt));
 end loop;
end;
```