# Oracle sql query with all mandatory values in where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write one select query in ORACLE which will return records only if all values given in where condition exists. E.g.

```
select * from emp where empid in (7521,7566,7698)
```

Now I want to write this query so that it should return value ONLY when all 3 empid exists.  It will be like AND condition i.e. empid = 7521 and empid = 7566 and empid = 7698.  If any one value does not exist then this query should not fetch any row.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672545/55922 for how to turn a list of values into something you can use in an IN statement.  From there, to make sure you have all of them I would recommend using the analytic function to count the values suggested by a_horse_with_no_name and make sure that matches the number of items in your list, which can be found using length(id_list) - length(replace(id_list,',')) + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension to Lukas' version where you need to write the IDs only once:

```
with emp_ids as (
   select 7521 as eid from dual
   union all 
   select 7566 from dual
   union all
   select 7698 from dual
)
select * 
from (
  select emp.*, 
         count(*) over() as cnt
  from emp_new emp
  where empid in (select eid from emp_ids)
)
where cnt = (select count(*) from emp_ids);
```

In these cases I always miss the standard row constructor that is available in other DBMS, where I can simply write `VALUES (7521), (7566), (7698)` to generate a virtual table with the desired values without the need to use DUAL...

Comment: Now there are some complexities here i.e. the eid which we are retrieving from emp_ids also have some parents,  So my count will increase there.

Comment: That's not what you described in your question or your comments to Lukas' answer (and I'm not sure what you mean with "*have some parent*")

Comment: Nice solution. I haven't thought of CTE's for constructing ad-hoc in-memory tables. Indeed, it's a pity, that there isn't even any default `TABLE` or `VARRAY` type available in Oracle...

Comment: @user1017936: if that solution works perfectly, perhaps you should accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Run the same query again, as a nested select, and count its records

```
select * from emp 
where empid in (7521, 7566, 7698)
and 3 = (select count(*) from emp where empid in (7521, 7566, 7698))
```

Alternatively, use an analytic function on the original result and check on that:

```
select * from (
  select emp.*, count(*) over() as cnt
  from emp where empid in (7521, 7566, 7698)
)
where cnt = 3
```

Comment: but here my in condition is dynamic, it is not fixed to 3 only

Comment: @user1017936: I imagine, you can render it dynamically, then? Where do you store the relevant ID's?

Comment: Actually it is used to for some search condition.  Yes I can take count but again there is one problem user will enter values in string with comma separated values so I cant use IN query.

Comment: @user1017936: I'm not sure if I understand... But I guess that's a new unrelated problem, which deserves a new question. As far as the query goes, I gave you two valid options.