# How can I get the rows that matches all values of a list passed as a parameter?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a java method that receives a list of strings as a parameter and I want to get the row(s) that matches exactly all the values of the list (no more, no less).

I have two tables (a Cases table and a Products table) that has a many-to-many relationship.

```
CASES_TABLE
ID    CASES_COMMENT       ...
1      Some comment       ...
2      Some comment2      ...
3      Some comment3      ...
...        ...

PRODUCTS_TABLE
ID   PRODUCT_CODE
1     VoIP
2     IPTV
3     PSTN
...    ...

 CASES_PRODUCTS_TABLE
CASE_ID   PRODUCT_ID
1         1
2         1
2         2
2         3
3         1
3         2
...    ...
```

I'm using Oracle as the rdbms.

For instance:

```
Given the list:
  List<String> products = Stream.of("VoIP", "IPTV","PSTN").collect(Collectors.toList());;
```

And the method
String getSomeValue (List products);

What I'd want get is the case with the id 2, because that's the one that matches exactly all the values (not the case with the id 1 because it matches only one value, and not the case with the id 2 because it matches only two values).

I've read about relational division, but I thinks it doesn't solve my problem. I've also try with the IN condition but it performs an 'OR' and I want my query to filter exactly by all values without leaving one left or getting a row that has a value that wasn't present on the list.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT CASES_COMMENT
FROM CASES_TABLE CT JOIN CASES_PRODUCTS_TABLE CPT
ON CT.ID = CPT.CASE_ID
JOIN PRODUCTS_TABLE
ON PT.ID = CPT.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE IN ('VoIP', 'PSTN', 'IPTV');
```

Comment: Explain your question with some sample data and expected results - will make things clearer

Comment: Shou what you have tried.

Comment: I'm not sure this is supported by JQL but HQL has [collection expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-collection-expressions) that might provide what you need.

Comment: @JGFMK Done, thanks

Comment: @TheImpaler I explained it on a coment, now I posted the query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it with JQL is with sub queries

Example:

```
SELECT CASES_COMMENT
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM CASES_TABLE CT JOIN CASES_PRODUCTS_TABLE CPT
            ON CT.ID = CPT.CASE_ID
            JOIN PRODUCTS_TABLE
            ON PT.ID = CPT.PRODUCT_ID
            WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'VoIP') as cond1
      WHERE cond1.PRODUCT_CODE = 'PSTN') as cond2
WHERE cond2.PRODUCT_CODE = 'IPTV'
```

Of course u can create it dynamically to fit as many strings as u want.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways (Analytic function being one of them)
Look at this answer for hints
[Oracle sql query with all mandatory values in where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926507/oracle-sql-query-with-all-mandatory-values-in-where-condition)

One solution by reusing your own query is

```
select CASES_COMMENT from
(select CASES_COMMENT , count(*) occurance from (
SELECT CASES_COMMENT
FROM CASES_TABLE CT JOIN CASES_PRODUCTS_TABLE CPT
ON CT.ID = CPT.CASE_ID
JOIN PRODUCTS_TABLE PT
ON PT.ID = CPT.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE IN ('VOIP', 'PSTN', 'IPTV'))
group by cases_comment)
where occurance = 3;
```

For this query you would need another input, which is the length or size of the input Array you are looking for

Sql Fiddle Link with example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29cd9/5

Comment: Apparently it does not work when it has all the products on the query plus a few more (or at least 1 more)

Comment: What do you mean? did you hard code the number '3'?, it should be equal to no of products in input.

Answer (score 0):

I think that grouping and counting should produce what you need:

```
select
    cp.case_id
  from products_table p
  join cases_products_table cp on cp.product_id = p.id
  where p.product_code in ('VoIP', 'PSTN', 'IPTV')
  group by cp.case_id
  having count(*) = 3
```

This query should return only `CASE_ID` = 2, since that's the only one that has three products.

Comment: I'm finding that it also returns the IDs of the cases that not only has the three products mentioned but also other products.

Comment: How so? There's a filter right there: `where p.product_code in ('VoIP', 'PSTN', 'IPTV')` What other products is the query finding?

Comment: Trying it out in "real life" it also returns the id of the cases that has as products: VoIP, PSTN, IPTV and DTH.