# Passing string variable into WHERE IN statement at another procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a variable call Name in a Procedure call getName

```
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Name : ' || Name);

Output result
-------------
Name : 'John', 'Test'
```

However when I try pass in the Name variable into 'Where IN ()' statement in another procedure, it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
Where Name IN (Name);
```

Wouldn't that statement equivalent to

```
Where Name IN ('John', 'Test');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to make it dynamic String only..

Comment: Oops... second link was supposed to be to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672545/266304), which links to [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425).

Comment: In addition to what Alex says, using a variable name that is identical to a column name is likely to cause confusion in anybody who tries to read your code.