# convert varchar value to array to varchar sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have table named departments has column  named `tax_code` `nvarchar2` datatype saved value `01,33,E1`

when i want to use this value in this code

```
select id,name from employee 
where taxcode in( select tax_code from department)
```

give me the value

```
where taxcode in('01,33,E1') this wrong
```

i want this

```
where taxcode in('01','33','E1')
```

regards

above in details i explain

Comment: Just don't store comma-separated strings when you are interested in the separate values. This violates database normalization (first normal form). Make this a proper table with one value per row and your query will run just fine.

Comment: ... or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672545/using-the-in-clause-with-a-comma-delimited-string-from-the-output-of-a-replace

Comment: Since it was closed a second before I was able to answer and I don't want my work to go to waste: you can try the following query: https://dbfiddle.uk/nu4YaNLb . As mentioned above, you should address how your data is being entered into the database because it violates 1NF - its best to fix it at the root.